# How to create SharePoint List Item from PowerApps with Current User credential

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps app that submits a form to a SharePoint list. I have a service account that was used to create the app. When the form submits to SharePoint, the service account is listed in the "Created By" field. Is there any way to pass the current logged in user credentials so that the item is created by the user clicking the Submit button, rather than the service account?

Comment: How are you creating list item in SharePoint? using Power automate flow?

Comment: No- the PowerApp form has a Submit button on it that performs a SubmitForm(Form1); action.